# Sublime Text Dart package on Mac OS X - live analysis not working

Tags: dart, sublimetext3

I have been using Sublime Text and the [Dart package](https://github.com/guillermooo/dart-sublime-bundle) on Windows 7 with no problems. I now want to switch to Mac OS X.

I have Dart 1.22 installed via Homebrew and Sublime Text 3 Build 3126 installed via Homebrew Cask.

I tried setting the Dart package `dart_sdk_path` to `/usr/local/Cellar/dart/1.22.0` and `/usr/local/Cellar/dart/1.22.0/libexec`

Looking at the Sublime console I see

```
reloading plugin Dart.__init__
reloading plugin Dart._init_
reloading plugin Dart._init_check
reloading plugin Dart.AAA
reloading plugin Dart.analyzer
...
...
reloading plugin Dart.pub_support
reloading plugin Dart.run
reloading plugin Dart.stagehand
plugins loaded
Dart: Exception occurred during init. Aborting
==============================================
no analysis server found. Are you using a recent sdk?
```

Live analysis does not work. Nothing happens if I introduce a syntax error to a Dart file. (Running a simple Dart Program from inside the Dart package does work however).

Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with your setup. I'm afraid that the Sublime bundle hasn't been updated since 2015, and there has been a lot of progress since then in the Dart analyzer. You might want to [file an issue](https://github.com/guillermooo/dart-sublime-bundle/issues).

FWIW, the most popular Sublime-style editor right now seems to be [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), and that one has a fantastic and very popular [Dart plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanTup.dart-code). A lot of people are happy with IntelliJ WebStorm, which has the Dart plugin installed by default.

Comment: I'm rather disappointed that the Sublime plugin has not been updated for so long. I'm giving Atom a try, and I'll give VS Code a go too.